# iOS app can't connect to Firebase IID service - Location Bound?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, instanceid

I am working on an app and the Android version implements Firebase for Instance ID, Cloud Messaging and Analytics. Everything is working properly in regards to obtaining the instance id and FCM token.

I also built a server API for sending notifications and data payloads to Android devices and in order to use the same methods in the iOS version I decided to use Firebase for iOS for the same purposes (Instance ID, Cloud Messaging and Analytics).

Setting up Firebase on iOS is well documented and I was able to set the environment for everything to work properly. However, when I run the app I got the following error in the console (which means that the instance id and FCM token were not retrieved):

```
....
[Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID003009] Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=0 "(null)" 
[Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID003007] Failed to retrieve the default GCM token after 5 retries
```

Wait, I know there are other people complaining about the same issue here but this is a totally different case.

I thought that my setup was incorrect or missing something but I reviewed all the procedures and code and everything was 100% correct.

Where I am located (Damascus, Syria), some services are blocked by Google and can only be accessible via a proxy or a VPN. Therefore I setup a US proxy for both the device I am using for testing and the simulator and when I run the app everything works properly and I was able to get the instance id and the FCM token and log them in the console.

What is weird is that in the Firebase Console the analytics is showing the correct number of users even when the FCM token was not received which means that the communication with the Firebase service is not totally blocked. The only part which is not working (without a proxy) is fetching the FCM token.

My question is: Why this particular Firebase service is blocked in iOS and not in Android and can I do anything about it? Remember that I have no problem in getting the token in Android from the same location. Or is this a bug in Firebase and the service is not location bound?

I have no problem in connecting to Google APIs from my location for other purposes like Google Maps or getting information about an FCM token..etc. However, I noticed that the console is referring to **iid.firebase.com** instead of **iid.googleapis.com**.

Any help or suggestion in this regard will be appreciated because I want to make a decision whether I should keep trying to use Firebase in both platforms or if I should rely on Firebase for Android and the native APNs ways for iOS. Also, I want to know if my decision to implement Firebase was the correct one in the first place.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Damascus. Well structured question (details show research effort as well). However, I think this kind of question would be better questioned directly by [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) -- provided that you are 100% sure that it's not an issue with the code. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you AL for your helpful comment! I was following the recommended steps in Firebase Support website about seeking the help from the community before getting a direct support. Looks like this is what I will resort to eventually. Thanks again.